# How to get similar amount value in SQL as getting in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, format, currency, sqldatatypes

When in excel (262.41*1011)/4  gives 66323.16227( cell format is accounting with 2 decimal places). Whereas in SQL it gives 66324.127500.
Why and how can I get the same result as Excel.

Answer (score 0):

(262.41*1011)/4 gives 66324.127500(Correct answer) in Excel, with either number format or accounting format just as you specified. What version of excel do you use?

Comment: I am using office 12. The calculation is happening of two fields one is type general 1011 and another is Number with 2 decimal places 262.41. and there product is divided by 4.

Comment: Well, its still the same results..(262.41*1011)/4 = 66324.127500
when you multiply from two fields..